# Scala: performance boost on incremental garbage collection

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, jvm

I have written an application in Scala. Basically, the first step is to create a array of objects an then to initialise these objects from a csv file. When running the application on the jvm it is really slow, and after some experimenting I found out that using the -J-Xincgc flag which enables incremental garbage collection speeds up the application by a factor of 4 (it's 4 times faster with the switch!). I wonder:

1. Why?
2. Did I use some inefficient coding, and if so, where should I start to find out whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure performance? Could you paste a short example of your code?

Comment: Measure perfomance just be logging the time ... usual run takes about 50 seconds, with the -J-Xincgc switch about 12 seconds (which is still a lot :( )

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're running this on hotspot.

The hotspot JVM has a [whole zoo of garbage collectors](http://Assuming%20you're%20running%20it%20on%20hotspot%20then%20you%20should), most of which also may have some sort of sub-modes or various command-line switches that significantly alter their behavior.
Which GC is used by default varies based on JVM version, operating system and 32/64bit VM.
So you basically changed whatever the default was to a specific algorithm that happened to perform "faster" for your workload.

But "faster" is a fuzzy measure. Wall time is not the same as CPU cycles spent if you consider multi-threading. And some collectors may simply choose to grow the heap more aggressively, thus deferring the cost of collection to a later point in time, which you might not have measured if your program didn't run long enough.

To make an accurate assessment much more information would be needed

- what GC was used by default
- your VM version
- how many cores your CPU has
- what kind of workload do you have (multi/single-thread, long/short-running, expected memory footprint, object allocation rate)

[Oracle's GC tuning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/) guide may prove useful for you

In your case, `-Xincgc` translates to CMS in incremental mode, which is intended for single-core environments and has been deprecated as of java8. It probably just happened to be better than the default, but it's not necessarily an optimal choice.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: How do I get the gc-defaults?

Comment: `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to get all effective command line flags, but that's fairly verbose. A more concise view can be obtained with visualvm + the visualgc plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you get into a situation where you are running close to your heap-size limit, you can waste a lot of GC time, which can lead to a lot of false findings about performance.  If that's your situation, first increase your heap-size limit before doing anything else.  Consider use of [jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) to eyeball the situation - it's trivially easy to get started with.